# Unable to update value of textarea by using a loop in chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects

Hello I am new to Javascript. I am trying to change value of a textarea in HTML page in runtime using chrome dev console. I have an array of questions and I want to enter them in input textarea one by one synchronously by using a loop in chrome dev console. I am able to change the value by using following command

`$('textarea').value= "This is a sample text";`

The problem occurs when I put that statement in a loop. Instead of running synchronously while the loop is running, it seems like the statement of each itereation get stack up and fires once all iterations of loop are complete.

```
const qlist = ["This is sample text 1", "This is sample text 2", "This is sample text 3"];
for (let x of qlist) {
     $('textarea').value= x;
};
```

Comment: So what is your desired effect?

Comment: The loop runs synchronously as expected, but since you simply replace value in the textarea, at the end of the loop all you see is the last item from the array. If you use `value += x` you'll see all items appended

Comment: @vanowm, your solution is correct. Also ``$("textarea").append(x);`` can be used, no?

Comment: sure, if you don't care about performance...(I'm not a fan of using non-vanilla-javascript bloatware)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to add all array items to the textarea, or replace one by one.

**1. Add all array items to textarea**

To add all array items to a textarea, convert the array to a newline delimited string:

```
let el = document.createElement('textarea');
document.body.appendChild(el);
const qList = ["Sample text 1", "Sample text 2", "Sample text 3"];
el.value = qList.join('\n');
```

**1. Replace textarea with array items one by one**

In your example you replace the textarea value quickly, so you only see the last item in the textarea. You can introduce a delay between textarea updates, here with `await sleep(1000)`:

```
const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));

const updateTextarea = async function(el, arr) {
  for (let str of arr) {
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(str);
    el.value= str;
  };
}

let el = document.createElement('textarea');
document.body.appendChild(el);
const qList = ["Sample text 1", "Sample text 2", "Sample text 3"];
updateTextarea(el, qList);
```

You can paste these examples into the Chrome console.

Comment: FYI you don't need `await` in the last line. Also, you do know you could post it as snippet, right?

Comment: @vanowm: You are right, I removed the last `await` since we do not have anything else to run after that

Comment: @PeterThoeny Thankyou so much for your reponse. First of all I want to let you know that actually I am trying to interact with a chat box so I have to load the first  sample text in the text input area, click on send button and get the repsonse saved in an array and then do the similar next iteration with the second sample text.   I have added the delay and through console.log I can see that await function is working but the thing is value of input text area load only after last iteration.

Comment: It feels like the command to load text in input text area is being stacked up and fires only after last iteration is done. While I want to fire it while the loop is running.